# Xcode 6 Testing on 4-inch device, but showing 3.5 inch view

Tags: ios

Using xcode 6, when I try to debug using my iphone 5, the screen shows an iphone 4s version. Anybody know what is wrong with this? I have tried changing inferred version on file inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a default launch image for each screen size for it to work properly.

Create an image asset catalog and add your default launch images for each size there.

Go to your project and look at Launch Image Source and press Use Asset Catalog:
[image]

And then in your asset catalog > Launch Images insert your images (and select the sizes you support):
[image]